# Is there any reason to use CopyToAsync between two MemoryStreams

Tags: c#

You know both streams are memory streams. Both streams are backed by byte buffers in memory, so is there any point using CopyToAsync vs CopyTo? A trivial example:

```
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
...//do something to add data to stream1
await stream1.CopyToAsync(stream2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, all "asynchronous" methods on `MemoryStream` are actually synchronous. `CopyToAsync` and friends only exist on `MemoryStream` because they exist on `Stream`.

Using `CopyToAsync` would make sense if one or the other of the streams had true asynchronous operations, but if you know both streams are `MemoryStream`, then you can just call `CopyTo` and get the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

hmm, should have looked at the [implementation for MemoryStream](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs) before asking:

```
// If destination is a MemoryStream, CopyTo synchronously:
memStrDest.Write(_buffer, pos, n);
```

So, no point.

Will leave question here in case it helps someone else.